# Scraping weird table structure using beautiful soup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a couple of tables from this [website](https://www.etoro.com/trading/fees/#cfds) which are hidden under an expand button. However it looks like the table structure is really weird and I'm having trouble.

my code so far is

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

groups = ['Currencies', 'Commodities', 'Indices']
assets = {'Currencies': ['eur/usd','gbp/usd', 'usd/jpy'], 'Commodities': ['gold', 'silver', 'copper'], 'Indices': ['spx50', 'dj30']}


browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'/usr/local/bin/chromedriver', options=Options())
browser.get('https://www.etoro.com/trading/fees/#cfds')
soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'lxml')
```

My goal is to get the fees from the 'Spreads' section of the site (not the 'Overnight Fees' section), for each of the asset groups in my `groups` variable, and for each of those groups, those individual assets in the `assets` section. e.g. something like this for each group

```
| Instrument | Fee    |
|------------|--------|
| eur/usd    | 1 Pips |
| gbp/usd    | 2 Pips |
| usd/jpy    | 1 Pips |
```

Here is an example of the Currencies table html from beautiful soup:

```
<thead>
<tr>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr class="tr-decade-0" data-decade="0" data-search_val="eurusd eur/usd">
<td class="id-1"><a class="e-info" href="/markets/eurusd">
<div class="image" style='background-image:url("https://etoro-cdn.etorostatic.com/market-avatars/eur-usd/150x150.png")'></div>
<div class="details">
<div class="symbol">EURUSD</div>
<div class="name">EUR/USD</div>
</div>
</a></td><td data-th="Spread"><span class="spread_num">1</span> Pips</td></tr>
<tr class="tr-decade-0" data-decade="0" data-search_val="usdjpy usd/jpy">
<td class="id-5"><a class="e-info" href="/markets/usdjpy">
<div class="image" style='background-image:url("https://etoro-cdn.etorostatic.com/market-avatars/usd-jpy/150x150.png")'></div>
<div class="details">
<div class="symbol">USDJPY</div>
<div class="name">USD/JPY</div>
</div>
</a></td><td data-th="Spread"><span class="spread_num">1</span> Pips</td></tr>
<tr class="tr-decade-0" data-decade="0" data-search_val="gbpusd gbp/usd">
<td class="id-2"><a class="e-info" href="/markets/gbpusd">
<div class="image" style='background-image:url("https://etoro-cdn.etorostatic.com/market-avatars/gbp-usd/150x150.png")'></div>
<div class="details">
<div class="symbol">GBPUSD</div>
<div class="name">GBP/USD</div>
</div>
</a></td><td data-th="Spread"><span class="spread_num">2</span> Pips</td></tr>
<tr class="tr-decade-0" data-decade="0" data-search_val="usdchf usd/chf">
<td class="id-6"><a class="e-info" href="/markets/usdchf">
<div class="image" style='background-image:url("https://etoro-cdn.etorostatic.com/market-avatars/usd-chf/150x150.png")'></div>
<div class="details">
<div class="symbol">USDCHF</div>
<div class="name">USD/CHF</div>
</div>
</a></td><td data-th="Spread"><span class="spread_num">1.5</span> Pips</td></tr>
<tr class="tr-decade-0" data-decade="0" data-search_val="nzdusd nzd/usd">
<td class="id-3"><a class="e-info" href="/markets/nzdusd">
<div class="image" style='background-image:url("https://etoro-cdn.etorostatic.com/market-avatars/nzd-usd/150x150.png")'></div>
<div class="details">
<div class="symbol">NZDUSD</div>
<div class="name">NZD/USD</div>
</div>
</a></td><td data-th="Spread"><span class="spread_num">2.5</span> Pips</td></tr>
<tr class="tr-decade-0" data-decade="0" data-search_val="eurgbp eur/gbp">
<td class="id-8"><a class="e-info" href="/markets/eurgbp">
<div class="image" style='background-image:url("https://etoro-cdn.etorostatic.com/market-avatars/eur-gbp/150x150.png")'></div>
<div class="details">
<div class="symbol">EURGBP</div>
<div class="name">EUR/GBP</div>
</div>
</a></td><td data-th="Spread"><span class="spread_num">1.5</span> Pips</td></tr>
<tr class="tr-decade-0" data-decade="0" data-search_val="eurjpy eur/jpy">
<td class="id-10"><a class="e-info" href="/markets/eurjpy">
<div class="image" style='background-image:url("https://etoro-cdn.etorostatic.com/market-avatars/eur-jpy/150x150.png")'></div>
<div class="details">
<div class="symbol">EURJPY</div>
<div class="name">EUR/JPY</div>
</div>
</a></td><td data-th="Spread"><span class="spread_num">2</span> Pips</td></tr>
<tr class="tr-decade-0" data-decade="0" data-search_val="gbpjpy gbp/jpy">
<td class="id-11"><a class="e-info" href="/markets/gbpjpy">
<div class="image" style='background-image:url("https://etoro-cdn.etorostatic.com/market-avatars/gbp-jpy/150x150.png")'></div>
<div class="details">
<div class="symbol">GBPJPY</div>
<div class="name">GBP/JPY</div>
</div>
</a></td><td data-th="Spread"><span class="spread_num">3</span> Pips</td></tr>
<tr class="tr-decade-0" data-decade="0" data-search_val="audjpy aud/jpy">
<td class="id-14"><a class="e-info" href="/markets/audjpy">
<div class="image" style='background-image:url("https://etoro-cdn.etorostatic.com/market-avatars/aud-jpy/150x150.png")'></div>
<div class="details">
<div class="symbol">AUDJPY</div>
<div class="name">AUD/JPY</div>
</div>
</a></td><td data-th="Spread"><span class="spread_num">2</span> Pips</td></tr>
<tr class="tr-decade-0" data-decade="0" data-search_val="audusd aud/usd">
<td class="id-7"><a class="e-info" href="/markets/audusd">
<div class="image" style='background-image:url("https://etoro-cdn.etorostatic.com/market-avatars/aud-usd/150x150.png")'></div>
<div class="details">
<div class="symbol">AUDUSD</div>
<div class="name">AUD/USD</div>
</div>
</a></td><td data-th="Spread"><span class="spread_num">1</span> Pips</td></tr>
<tr class="tr-decade-1" data-decade="1" data-search_val="eurchf eur/chf">
<td class="id-9"><a class="e-info" href="/markets/eurchf">
<div class="image" style='background-image:url("https://etoro-cdn.etorostatic.com/market-avatars/eur-chf/150x150.png")'></div>
<div class="details">
<div class="symbol">EURCHF</div>
<div class="name">EUR/CHF</div>
</div>
</a></td><td data-th="Spread"><span class="spread_num">5</span> Pips</td></tr>
<tr class="tr-decade-1" data-decade="1" data-search_val="euraud eur/aud">
<td class="id-12"><a class="e-info" href="/markets/euraud">
<div class="image" style='background-image:url("https://etoro-cdn.etorostatic.com/market-avatars/eur-aud/150x150.png")'></div>
<div class="details">
<div class="symbol">EURAUD</div>
<div class="name">EUR/AUD</div>
</div>
</a></td><td data-th="Spread"><span class="spread_num">7</span> Pips</td></tr>
<tr class="tr-decade-1" data-decade="1" data-search_val="eurcad eur/cad">
<td class="id-13"><a class="e-info" href="/markets/eurcad">
<div class="image" style='background-image:url("https://etoro-cdn.etorostatic.com/market-avatars/eur-cad/150x150.png")'></div>
<div class="details">
<div class="symbol">EURCAD</div>
<div class="name">EUR/CAD</div>
</div>
</a></td><td data-th="Spread"><span class="spread_num">7</span> Pips</td></tr>
<tr class="tr-decade-1" data-decade="1" data-search_val="cadjpy cad/jpy">
<td class="id-15"><a class="e-info" href="/markets/cadjpy">
<div class="image" style='background-image:url("https://etoro-cdn.etorostatic.com/market-avatars/cad-jpy/150x150.png")'></div>
<div class="details">
<div class="symbol">CADJPY</div>
<div class="name">CAD/JPY</div>
</div>
</a></td><td data-th="Spread"><span class="spread_num">6</span> Pips</td></tr>
<tr class="tr-decade-1" data-decade="1" data-search_val="chfjpy chf/jpy">
<td class="id-16"><a class="e-info" href="/markets/chfjpy">
<div class="image" style='background-image:url("https://etoro-cdn.etorostatic.com/market-avatars/chf-jpy/150x150.png")'></div>
<div class="details">
<div class="symbol">CHFJPY</div>
<div class="name">CHF/JPY</div>
</div>
</a></td><td data-th="Spread"><span class="spread_num">6</span> Pips</td></tr>
<tr class="tr-decade-1" data-decade="1" data-search_val="usdhkd usd/hkd">
<td class="id-39"><a class="e-info" href="/markets/usdhkd">
<div class="image" style='background-image:url("https://etoro-cdn.etorostatic.com/market-avatars/usd-hkd/150x150.png")'></div>
<div class="details">
<div class="symbol">USDHKD</div>
<div class="name">USD/HKD</div>
</div>
</a></td><td data-th="Spread"><span class="spread_num">5</span> Pips</td></tr>
<tr class="tr-decade-1" data-decade="1" data-search_val="usdzar usd/zar">
<td class="id-42"><a class="e-info" href="/markets/usdzar">
<div class="image" style='background-image:url("https://etoro-cdn.etorostatic.com/market-avatars/usd-zar/150x150.png")'></div>
<div class="details">
<div class="symbol">USDZAR</div>
<div class="name">USD/ZAR</div>
</div>
</a></td><td data-th="Spread"><span class="spread_num">50</span> Pips</td></tr>
<tr class="tr-decade-1" data-decade="1" data-search_val="usdrub usd/rub">
<td class="id-44"><a class="e-info" href="/markets/usdrub">
<div class="image" style='background-image:url("https://etoro-cdn.etorostatic.com/market-avatars/usd-rub/150x150.png")'></div>
<div class="details">
<div class="symbol">USDRUB</div>
<div class="name">USD/RUB</div>
</div>
</a></td><td data-th="Spread"><span class="spread_num">3</span> Pips</td></tr>
<tr class="tr-decade-1" data-decade="1" data-search_val="usdcnh usd/cnh">
<td class="id-45"><a class="e-info" href="/markets/usdcnh">
<div class="image" style='background-image:url("https://etoro-cdn.etorostatic.com/market-avatars/usd-cnh/150x150.png")'></div>
<div class="details">
<div class="symbol">USDCNH</div>
<div class="name">USD/CNH</div>
</div>
</a></td><td data-th="Spread"><span class="spread_num">10</span> Pips</td></tr>
<tr class="tr-decade-1" data-decade="1" data-search_val="audchf aud/chf">
<td class="id-46"><a class="e-info" href="/markets/audchf">
<div class="image" style='background-image:url("https://etoro-cdn.etorostatic.com/market-avatars/aud-chf/150x150.png")'></div>
<div class="details">
<div class="symbol">AUDCHF</div>
<div class="name">AUD/CHF</div>
</div>
</a></td><td data-th="Spread"><span class="spread_num">4</span> Pips</td></tr>
<tr class="tr-decade-2" data-decade="2" data-search_val="audcad aud/cad">
<td class="id-47"><a class="e-info" href="/markets/audcad">
<div class="image" style='background-image:url("https://etoro-cdn.etorostatic.com/market-avatars/aud-cad/150x150.png")'></div>
<div class="details">
<div class="symbol">AUDCAD</div>
<div class="name">AUD/CAD</div>
</div>
</a></td><td data-th="Spread"><span class="spread_num">4</span> Pips</td></tr>
<tr class="tr-decade-2" data-decade="2" data-search_val="audnzd aud/nzd">
<td class="id-48"><a class="e-info" href="/markets/audnzd">
<div class="image" style='background-image:url("https://etoro-cdn.etorostatic.com/market-avatars/aud-nzd/150x150.png")'></div>
<div class="details">
<div class="symbol">AUDNZD</div>
<div class="name">AUD/NZD</div>
</div>
</a></td><td data-th="Spread"><span class="spread_num">4</span> Pips</td></tr>
<tr class="tr-decade-2" data-decade="2" data-search_val="eurnzd eur/nzd">
<td class="id-49"><a class="e-info" href="/markets/eurnzd">
<div class="image" style='background-image:url("https://etoro-cdn.etorostatic.com/market-avatars/eur-nzd/150x150.png")'></div>
<div class="details">
<div class="symbol">EURNZD</div>
<div class="name">EUR/NZD</div>
</div>
</a></td><td data-th="Spread"><span class="spread_num">4</span> Pips</td></tr>
<tr class="tr-decade-2" data-decade="2" data-search_val="gbpaud gbp/aud">
<td class="id-50"><a class="e-info" href="/markets/gbpaud">
<div class="image" style='background-image:url("https://etoro-cdn.etorostatic.com/market-avatars/gbp-aud/150x150.png")'></div>
<div class="details">
<div class="symbol">GBPAUD</div>
<div class="name">GBP/AUD</div>
</div>
</a></td><td data-th="Spread"><span class="spread_num">4</span> Pips</td></tr>
<tr class="tr-decade-2" data-decade="2" data-search_val="gbpchf gbp/chf">
<td class="id-51"><a class="e-info" href="/markets/gbpchf">
<div class="image" style='background-image:url("https://etoro-cdn.etorostatic.com/market-avatars/gbp-chf/150x150.png")'></div>
<div class="details">
<div class="symbol">GBPCHF</div>
<div class="name">GBP/CHF</div>
</div>
</a></td><td data-th="Spread"><span class="spread_num">4</span> Pips</td></tr>
<tr class="tr-decade-2" data-decade="2" data-search_val="gbpnzd gbp/nzd">
<td class="id-52"><a class="e-info" href="/markets/gbpnzd">
<div class="image" style='background-image:url("https://etoro-cdn.etorostatic.com/market-avatars/gbp-nzd/150x150.png")'></div>
<div class="details">
<div class="symbol">GBPNZD</div>
<div class="name">GBP/NZD</div>
</div>
</a></td><td data-th="Spread"><span class="spread_num">4</span> Pips</td></tr>
<tr class="tr-decade-2" data-decade="2" data-search_val="nzdcad nzd/cad">
<td class="id-53"><a class="e-info" href="/markets/nzdcad">
<div class="image" style='background-image:url("https://etoro-cdn.etorostatic.com/market-avatars/nzd-cad/150x150.png")'></div>
<div class="details">
<div class="symbol">NZDCAD</div>
<div class="name">NZD/CAD</div>
</div>
</a></td><td data-th="Spread"><span class="spread_num">4</span> Pips</td></tr>
<tr class="tr-decade-2" data-decade="2" data-search_val="nzdchf nzd/chf">
<td class="id-54"><a class="e-info" href="/markets/nzdchf">
<div class="image" style='background-image:url("https://etoro-cdn.etorostatic.com/market-avatars/nzd-chf/150x150.png")'></div>
<div class="details">
<div class="symbol">NZDCHF</div>
<div class="name">NZD/CHF</div>
</div>
</a></td><td data-th="Spread"><span class="spread_num">4</span> Pips</td></tr>
<tr class="tr-decade-2" data-decade="2" data-search_val="nzdjpy nzd/jpy">
<td class="id-55"><a class="e-info" href="/markets/nzdjpy">
<div class="image" style='background-image:url("https://etoro-cdn.etorostatic.com/market-avatars/nzd-jpy/150x150.png")'></div>
<div class="details">
<div class="symbol">NZDJPY</div>
<div class="name">NZD/JPY</div>
</div>
</a></td><td data-th="Spread"><span class="spread_num">4</span> Pips</td></tr>
<tr class="tr-decade-2" data-decade="2" data-search_val="cadchf cad/chf">
<td class="id-56"><a class="e-info" href="/markets/cadchf">
<div class="image" style='background-image:url("https://etoro-cdn.etorostatic.com/market-avatars/cad-chf/150x150.png")'></div>
<div class="details">
<div class="symbol">CADCHF</div>
<div class="name">CAD/CHF</div>
</div>
</a></td><td data-th="Spread"><span class="spread_num">4</span> Pips</td></tr>
<tr class="tr-decade-3" data-decade="3" data-search_val="usdnok usd/nok">
<td class="id-57"><a class="e-info" href="/markets/usdnok">
<div class="image" style='background-image:url("https://etoro-cdn.etorostatic.com/market-avatars/usd-nok/150x150.png")'></div>
<div class="details">
<div class="symbol">USDNOK</div>
<div class="name">USD/NOK</div>
</div>
</a></td><td data-th="Spread"><span class="spread_num">20</span> Pips</td></tr>
<tr class="tr-decade-3" data-decade="3" data-search_val="usdsek usd/sek">
<td class="id-58"><a class="e-info" href="/markets/usdsek">
<div class="image" style='background-image:url("https://etoro-cdn.etorostatic.com/market-avatars/usd-sek/150x150.png")'></div>
<div class="details">
<div class="symbol">USDSEK</div>
<div class="name">USD/SEK</div>
</div>
</a></td><td data-th="Spread"><span class="spread_num">20</span> Pips</td></tr>
<tr class="tr-decade-3" data-decade="3" data-search_val="noksek nok/sek">
<td class="id-59"><a class="e-info" href="/markets/noksek">
<div class="image" style='background-image:url("https://etoro-cdn.etorostatic.com/market-avatars/nok-sek/150x150.png")'></div>
<div class="details">
<div class="symbol">NOKSEK</div>
<div class="name">NOK/SEK</div>
</div>
</a></td><td data-th="Spread"><span class="spread_num">20</span> Pips</td></tr>
<tr class="tr-decade-3" data-decade="3" data-search_val="eurnok eur/nok">
<td class="id-60"><a class="e-info" href="/markets/eurnok">
<div class="image" style='background-image:url("https://etoro-cdn.etorostatic.com/market-avatars/eur-nok/150x150.png")'></div>
<div class="details">
<div class="symbol">EURNOK</div>
<div class="name">EUR/NOK</div>
</div>
</a></td><td data-th="Spread"><span class="spread_num">20</span> Pips</td></tr>
<tr class="tr-decade-3" data-decade="3" data-search_val="eursek eur/sek">
<td class="id-61"><a class="e-info" href="/markets/eursek">
<div class="image" style='background-image:url("https://etoro-cdn.etorostatic.com/market-avatars/eur-sek/150x150.png")'></div>
<div class="details">
<div class="symbol">EURSEK</div>
<div class="name">EUR/SEK</div>
</div>
</a></td><td data-th="Spread"><span class="spread_num">30</span> Pips</td></tr>
<tr class="tr-decade-3" data-decade="3" data-search_val="usdtry usd/try">
<td class="id-62"><a class="e-info" href="/markets/usdtry">
<div class="image" style='background-image:url("https://etoro-cdn.etorostatic.com/market-avatars/usd-try/150x150.png")'></div>
<div class="details">
<div class="symbol">USDTRY</div>
<div class="name">USD/TRY</div>
</div>
</a></td><td data-th="Spread"><span class="spread_num">50</span> Pips</td></tr>
<tr class="tr-decade-3" data-decade="3" data-search_val="usdmxn usd/mxn">
<td class="id-63"><a class="e-info" href="/markets/usdmxn">
<div class="image" style='background-image:url("https://etoro-cdn.etorostatic.com/market-avatars/usd-mxn/150x150.png")'></div>
<div class="details">
<div class="symbol">USDMXN</div>
<div class="name">USD/MXN</div>
</div>
</a></td><td data-th="Spread"><span class="spread_num">20</span> Pips</td></tr>
<tr class="tr-decade-3" data-decade="3" data-search_val="usdsgd usd/sgd">
<td class="id-64"><a class="e-info" href="/markets/usdsgd">
<div class="image" style='background-image:url("https://etoro-cdn.etorostatic.com/market-avatars/usd-sgd/150x150.png")'></div>
<div class="details">
<div class="symbol">USDSGD</div>
<div class="name">USD/SGD</div>
</div>
</a></td><td data-th="Spread"><span class="spread_num">3</span> Pips</td></tr>
<tr class="tr-decade-3" data-decade="3" data-search_val="gbpcad gbp/cad">
<td class="id-65"><a class="e-info" href="/markets/gbpcad">
<div class="image" style='background-image:url("https://etoro-cdn.etorostatic.com/market-avatars/gbp-cad/150x150.png")'></div>
<div class="details">
<div class="symbol">GBPCAD</div>
<div class="name">GBP/CAD</div>
</div>
</a></td><td data-th="Spread"><span class="spread_num">4</span> Pips</td></tr>
<tr class="tr-decade-3" data-decade="3" data-search_val="zarjpy zar/jpy">
<td class="id-66"><a class="e-info" href="/markets/zarjpy">
<div class="image" style='background-image:url("https://etoro-cdn.etorostatic.com/market-avatars/zar-jpy/150x150.png")'></div>
<div class="details">
<div class="symbol">ZARJPY</div>
<div class="name">ZAR/JPY</div>
</div>
</a></td><td data-th="Spread"><span class="spread_num">8</span> Pips</td></tr>
<tr class="tr-decade-4" data-decade="4" data-search_val="eurpln eur/pln">
<td class="id-68"><a class="e-info" href="/markets/eurpln">
<div class="image" style='background-image:url("https://etoro-cdn.etorostatic.com/market-avatars/eur-pln/150x150.png")'></div>
<div class="details">
<div class="symbol">EURPLN</div>
<div class="name">EUR/PLN</div>
</div>
</a></td><td data-th="Spread"><span class="spread_num">30</span> Pips</td></tr>
<tr class="tr-decade-4" data-decade="4" data-search_val="usdhuf usd/huf">
<td class="id-69"><a class="e-info" href="/markets/usdhuf">
<div class="image" style='background-image:url("https://etoro-cdn.etorostatic.com/market-avatars/usd-huf/150x150.png")'></div>
<div class="details">
<div class="symbol">USDHUF</div>
<div class="name">USD/HUF</div>
</div>
</a></td><td data-th="Spread"><span class="spread_num">20</span> Pips</td></tr>
<tr class="tr-decade-4" data-decade="4" data-search_val="eurhuf eur/huf">
<td class="id-70"><a class="e-info" href="/markets/eurhuf">
<div class="image" style='background-image:url("https://etoro-cdn.etorostatic.com/market-avatars/eur-huf/150x150.png")'></div>
<div class="details">
<div class="symbol">EURHUF</div>
<div class="name">EUR/HUF</div>
</div>
</a></td><td data-th="Spread"><span class="spread_num">20</span> Pips</td></tr>
<tr class="tr-decade-4" data-decade="4" data-search_val="gbphuf gbp/huf">
<td class="id-71"><a class="e-info" href="/markets/gbphuf">
<div class="image" style='background-image:url("https://etoro-cdn.etorostatic.com/market-avatars/gbp-huf/150x150.png")'></div>
<div class="details">
<div class="symbol">GBPHUF</div>
<div class="name">GBP/HUF</div>
</div>
</a></td><td data-th="Spread"><span class="spread_num">30</span> Pips</td></tr>
<tr class="tr-decade-4" data-decade="4" data-search_val="chfhuf chf/huf">
<td class="id-72"><a class="e-info" href="/markets/chfhuf">
<div class="image" style='background-image:url("https://etoro-cdn.etorostatic.com/market-avatars/chf-huf/150x150.png")'></div>
<div class="details">
<div class="symbol">CHFHUF</div>
<div class="name">CHF/HUF</div>
</div>
</a></td><td data-th="Spread"><span class="spread_num">30</span> Pips</td></tr>
<tr class="tr-decade-4" data-decade="4" data-search_val="usdpln usd/pln">
<td class="id-73"><a class="e-info" href="/markets/usdpln">
<div class="image" style='background-image:url("https://etoro-cdn.etorostatic.com/market-avatars/usd-pln/150x150.png")'></div>
<div class="details">
<div class="symbol">USDPLN</div>
<div class="name">USD/PLN</div>
</div>
</a></td><td data-th="Spread"><span class="spread_num">20</span> Pips</td></tr></tbody>
</table>
```

my first thought is to use a for loop for each one of my groups to identify the table using `soup.find`, then a for loop to search for the matching `tr` for each asset and extracting the relevant figure from `td`. However the website structure is confusing me too much so I'm having trouble coding it. can anybody help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your life easier and just dump the `HTML` to `pandas`. All the tables are there and you can access them either with a `for loop` or via `indexing`.

Here's how:

```python
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from tabulate import tabulate

options = Options()
options.headless = False
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get("https://www.etoro.com/trading/fees/#cfds")
df = pd.read_html(driver.page_source, flavor="bs4")
print(tabulate(df[-9]))
driver.close()
```

Sample output:

```
--  --------------------------------------------  ------------  ------------
 0  BTC Bitcoin                                   $ -11.813292  $ 0
 1  ETHEREUM Ethereum                             $ -0.300336   $ 0
 2  BCH Bitcoin Cash                              $ -0.138758   $ 0
 3  XRP Ripple                                    $ -0.00009    $ 0
 4  DASH Dash                                     $ -0.040001   $ 0
 5  LTC Litecoin                                  $ -0.049917   $ 0
 6  ETC Ethereum Classic                          $ -0.0023     $ 0
 7  ADA Cardano                                   $ -0.000072   $ 0
 8  MIOTA IOTA                                    $ -0.000119   $ 0
 9  XLM Stellar                                   $ -0.000051   $ 0
10  EOS EOS                                       $ -0.001041   $ 0
11  NEO NEO                                       $ -0.005731   $ 0
12  TRX TRON                                      $ -0.000011   $ 0
13  ZEC ZCASH                                     $ -0.02535    $ 0
14  BNB Binance Coin                              $ -0.014941   $ 0
15  XTZ Tezos                                     $ -0.000813   $ 0
16  LINK Chainlink                                $ -0.004082   $ 0
17  UNI Uniswap                                   $ -0.000816   $ 0
18  DOGE Dogecoin                                 $ -0.000163   $ -0.000163
19  BTCEUR Bitcoin/Euro                           $ -11.813292  $ 0
20  ETHEUR Ethereum/Euro                          $ -0.300336   $ 0

and so on ...
```

Note: For me, running in `headless` mode gives me a CAPTCHA. Hence, the head mode on.

Answer (score 1):

First, the code below expands all the spread listings, and then continues to click the "load more" buttons for each until all the records are displayed. However, both expanding the listing and clicking the load more will not change the overall element structure on the page, so you can skip this step and proceed to the next code block that actual grabs the data and produces the result from `groups` and `assets`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from selenium import webdriver
d = webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/chromedriver')
d.get('https://www.etoro.com/trading/fees/#cfds')
d.execute_script("""
   for (var i of document.querySelectorAll('span.expand-toggle')){
      i.click()
}""")
visible = d.execute_script("""
  return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('button.show-more')).map(function(x){
      var style = window.getComputedStyle(x);
      return style.getPropertyValue('display');
   });
""")
while 'block' in visible:
   d.execute_script("""
   for (var i of document.querySelectorAll('button.show-more')){
      i.click()
   }""")
   visible = d.execute_script("""
      return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('button.show-more')).map(function(x){
        var style = window.getComputedStyle(x);
        return style.getPropertyValue('display');
     });
   """)
```

---

Now, grabbing the tables (expanded, if the above block was run):

```
import re
page = soup(d.page_source, 'html.parser')
blocks = [i for i in page.select('div.page_single_tab.tab_2 div.e-row') if (k:=i['class'][-1].split('-')[-1]).isdigit() and 3 <= int(k) <= 8]
groups = ['Currencies', 'Commodities', 'Indices']
assets = {'Currencies': ['eur/usd','gbp/usd', 'usd/jpy'], 'Commodities': ['gold', 'silver', 'copper'], 'Indices': ['spx50', 'dj30']}
vals = {i.select_one('.expand-title-1').text: \
         {j.text.lower():k.select_one('.spread_num').text 
          for k in i.select('div.expand-content tr') if (j:=k.select_one('.name'))}
       for i in blocks}
result = {a:{i:vals[a].get(i) for i in b} for a, b in assets.items()}
```

Output:

```
{'Currencies': {'eur/usd': '1', 'gbp/usd': '2', 'usd/jpy': '1'}, 'Commodities': {'gold': '45', 'silver': '5', 'copper': '2'}, 'Indices': {'spx50': None, 'dj30': '600'}}
```